# Does document db support "not in"

Tags: aws-documentdb

Does document db support NOT IN operator. I can see in this document https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/querying.html other examples but not for this. Need help with syntax to have something like

```
db.example.find( NOT IN { "Item": ["item1","item2"]} AND {"Code":"code1"} ).pretty()
```

Answer (score 1):

DocumentDB supports $nin operator and you can use this operator to select documents where the field is not in a specified array. Please find below the updated query.

```
db.example.find({ $and: [{Item: {$nin:["item1","item2"]}} , {Code:"code1"}] })
```